# Creating a .NET Standard library that uses other MVC libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-standard-2.0, filecontentresult

I am trying to create a .NET Standard 2.0 library that is to be used by multiple MVC applications which may be .NET Framework or .NET Core.  This particular library is supposed to export data as an excel file.  To do this I need to use `FileContentResult` which is part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`(Core). I do not have options to install the Framework version of this library.

How would I go about implementing `FileContentResult` in my .NET Standard library so that it will work in both a Core or Framework application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library should not be working with something like `FileContentResult`. The single-responsibility principle dictates that it should handle only the functionality that's actually relevant to its purpose, namely creating an excel file from some set of data. You can then return this from your library as a `Stream`.

Whatever, then, is using your library will decide what to do with that `Stream`. In the case on an ASP.NET Core app, you might return it as a `FileStreamResult`. In another scenario, you might write it to the filesystem, or add it as an attachment to an email, etc. Tying it to one narrow scenario such as returning a file as response from a web app limits the usability of your library.

Long and short, the answer to your question is essentially you don't need to do this in the first place. Keep your library focused on what it's actually responsible for, and you don't need these types of dependencies.

Comment: I had a feeling this was going to be the answer.  Thanks Starlord

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you **need** to use `FileContentResult`. Just do your processing and return a byte array in your library. In your MVC application, call this method and create a `FileContentResult`.

Use abstractions instead of concrete types in such situations. You could also return a `Stream` or define your own abstraction.